# multidimensional associative array in C#

Tags: c#, arrays, list, arraylist

I am trying to find something where I can have a key/value list that contains a key/value list, so it would look something like this:

```
String Item 1
    +- key1 -> Object
    +- key2 -> Object
String Item 2
    +- key1 -> Object
    +- key2 -> Object
    +- key3 -> Object
    +- key4 -> Object
String Item 3
    +- key1 -> Object
```

In php It would look like this:

```
array(
    "String Item 1" => array(
        "key1" => Object,
        "key2" => Object
    ),
    "String Item 2" => array(
        "key1" => Object,
        "key2" => Object,
        "key3" => Object,
        "key4" => Object
    ),
    "String Item 3" => array(
        "key1" => Object
    )
);
```

Is there anything that can do that in C#?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can use a generic dictionary that uses a generic dictionary as the value:

```
var dict = new Dictionary<string, Dictionary<string, object>>();

// Adding a value
dict.Add("key", new Dictionary<string, object>()
{
    { "key1", "value1" },
    { "key2", "value2" }
});

// Retrieving value1
var result = dict["key"]["key1"];
```

Comment: That looks promising!

Comment: yeah.. generic dictionaries are pretty flexible and will give you better performance than the Hashtable class!