# Multidimensional associative array C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, multidimensional-array, associative-array

Coming from PHP background I could do this in PHP:

```
$array[sales_details][uid] = 1;
$array[sales_details][name] = "Name Surname";
$array[sales_details][sales][France][Paris] = 50;
$array[sales_details][sales][France][Lyon] = 25;
$array[sales_details][sales][UK][London] = 75;
$array[sales_details][sales][German][Berlin] = 23;
```

How can I do this in C#? I tried looking into Dictionary. But even if I define the value key as object it will not accept the "sales" array.

```
var dict = new Dictionary<string, object>();
dict["uid"] = 1;
dict["sales"]["France"]["Paris"] = 50; //error kicks in here
```

Is this possible with C#?

Comment: Jagged array could be one way or you create a typed object structure with classes, which represents this. If it is important for my, I would always create an object structure.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27095470/multidimensional-associative-array-in-c-sharp

Answer (score 2):

It seems to me you are trying to put *a lot* of information in an array, what actually has to be an object.

You can solve this with [jagged arrays](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2s05feca.aspx), but objects are way better.

Create a class like this:

```
public class SalesDetails
{
    public string Uid {get;set;}
    public string Name {get;set;}

    public List<SalesItem> SalesItems {get;set;} = new List<SalesItem>();
}
```

Then work out  yourself `SalesItem`, `City` and all other objects you need.

Answer (score 0):

When you want dynamic properties, try to use the [ExpandoObject](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.dynamic.expandoobject.aspx) class like this:

```
dynamic salesDetails = new ExpandoObject();
salesDetails.Uid = 10;

salesDetails.Sales = new ExpandoObject();

salesDetails.Sales.France = new ExpandoObject();
salesDetails.Sales.France.Paris = 50;
salesDetails.Sales.France.Lyon = 25;

salesDetails.Sales.UK = new ExpandoObject();
salesDetails.Sales.UK.London = 75;

salesDetails.Sales.Germany = new ExpandoObject();
salesDetails.Sales.Germany.Berlin = 23;

dynamic london = salesDetails.Sales.UK.London;
```

It is important, that you have to initialize also the inner properties as ExpandoObject.