# how to make a "multidimensional-associative-array" from an SQL result

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am working in ASP coming from a php background. (don't recommend that!)

I have db data to corrosponds to an unknown number of "groups" that each have an unknown number of "members"

In PHP I would just build the array like this;

```
foreach ($groups as $group) {
    foreach ($members as $member) {
        $array[$group][] = $member;
    }
}
```

This is over simplified, and would have SQL Query's etc, but you get the idea.

I would actually just `echo` the data in the loops to build my HTML.

How do I do this in ASP.  I have an ascx and ascx.cs file.  I can query my data fine, but don't know how to loop it and output it into the ascx file.

I have see [this answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34872932/multidimentional-associative-array-c-sharp/34873039), but don't follow.

I just can't wrap my head around these lists of lists with no keys etc.

The output is like this

```
-group1
    --member1
    --member2
    --member3
    --member4
-group2
    --member1
    --member2
-group3
    --member1
    --member2
    --member3
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could build a few classes for this, as one solution.

```
public class Member
{
    *member properties here*
}
public class Group 
{
    List<Member> Members {get;set;} = new List<Member>();
}
```

And to fill the object:

```
var groups = new List<Group>();
foreach (var *things* in *results*)
{
    Group group = new Group();
    foreach(var *stuff* in *things*)
    {
         Member member = new Member();
         member.*property* = *stuff*.*property*; (or perhaps this is in an array, just the array and then the correct index)
         group.add(member);
    }
    groups.add(group)
}
```

Then when adding it to your page, you can send this object there via a model, which will need to be attached to that page.

This is very vague perhaps, but it will give you a start. Welcome to object oriented!